# How do I randomly pick elements from an Array that satisfy a condition?

Tags: java

I have a player and group class which I've used to instantiate the following:

```
Player andrew = new Player(*name:* Andrew, *health:* 20)
Player samantha = new Player(*name:* Samantha, *health:* 32)
Player tony = new Player(*name:* Tony, *health:* 5)
Player flynn = new Player(*name:* Flynn, *health:* 0)
Player oliver = new Player(*name:* Oliver, *health:* 0)
Group myGroup = new Group(*player:* andrew, *player:* samantha, *player:* tony, *player:* flynn, *player:* oliver)
```

The following method, which I've defined in the group class puts all the players in the group in to an Array and returns it when evoked on the Group object:

```
myGroup.putIntoList()
```

So putting the line above would return:

```
[Player@andrew, Player@samantha, Player@tony, Player@flynn, Player@oliver]
```

where each element of the array is the player objects I created earlier.

I have also defined a .getHealth() method in my player class which returns the health of the player.

Getting to the main point,
I want to write a method in my Group class which chooses a player from that generated array at random that is also not dead (i.e. health is above 0)
This is what I've written so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random myNumber = new Random();
public Player pickOutAndReturn(){
   int anotherNumber = myNumber.nextInt(5);
   return this.putIntoList()[anotherNumber];
}
```

The trouble with this is that it can return any 5 of the players at random. How do I change it so that it only returns the alive members but at random **without removing the dead players from the array**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before choosing randomly, filter the array with:

```
Players [] health_players = Arrays.stream(this.putIntoList())
                                  .filter(i -> i.getHealth() > 0)
                                  .toArray();
```

only then choose randomly from the `health_players`.

```
Random myNumber = new Random();
public Player pickOutAndReturn(){
     Players [] health_players = Arrays.stream(this.putIntoList())
                                       .filter(i -> i.getHealth() > 0)
                                       .toArray();

   int anotherNumber = myNumber.nextInt(health_players.length);
   return health_players[anotherNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Player pickOutAndReturn() {
   // filter for alive players
   var alivePlayers = this.putIntoList().stream()
      .filter(player -> player.getHealth() > 0)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
      
   // pick a random player from list
   int anotherNumber = myNumber.nextInt(alivePlayers.size());
   return alivePlayer.get(anotherNumber);
```